# How to send form to controller using ajax in asp.net core?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm working on an online exam. I want to send the answers of the user to controller by Ajax. I have 3 kinds of question(descriptive,choice,true false) and for each of them I have foreach loop to show the questions.
This is the form:

```
<form id="QuestionsForm" asp-action="SubmitAnswers" asp-controller="Home" data-ajax="true" data-ajax- 
   method="post">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <h4>@item.QuestionTitle</h4>
            <p>
                @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                {
                    @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
                    {
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-choice="@i" name="group@(i)" class="group" 
                value="@choice.Choice">@choice.Choice
                        </label>
                    }
                  i++;
                }
                else
                @if (item.trueFalseQuestions.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                {
                    <!--truefalse-->
                  
                    @foreach (var question in item.trueFalseQuestions)
                    {
                        var convertToString = Convert.ToString(question.IsTrue);
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)" 
                 name="trueFalse@(trueFalse)" class="trueFalse" value="صحیح">صحیح
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)" 
                 name="trueFalse@(trueFalse)" class="trueFalse" value="غلط">غلط
                        </label>

                    }
                    trueFalse++;
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="QId" value="@item.QuestionId" />
                    <textarea class="descriptive" name="Descriptive" id="descriptive" 
                 placeholder="..."></textarea>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    QuestionCount++;
     }
     <input type="button" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="save">
 </form>
```

this is my ajax code:

```
@section script
   {
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $('#QuestionsForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#QuestionsForm').attr('action'),
            method: "Post",
            data: frm,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status === 'success') {
                alert("succeed");
            }
            else if (res.status === 'faild') {
                alert("faild");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

this is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SubmitAnswers([Bind("group,trueFalse,Descriptive")] Question model)
    {
        //todo
        return View();
    }
```

I want to get the all user's answers in controller but it returns null. Is this way a possible way?

Comment: Check the names of your input fields. The controller action expects **only** the names `group`, `trueFalse`, and `Descriptive`. Any other names, e.g. `group0`, will not be deserialized in your question model.

Comment: I didn't know that. but I need to name the elements like that. I used these names in my other codes. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: The names of the form elements are ultimately what is being sent via the POST. For example, your POST body might look like this: `group0=false&group1=true&group2=true`. So those names `group0`, `group1` etc. are what are received by the controller and it will need to map those somehow to the model object. – You could modify the names while keeping the form elements by building a custom [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object in JavaScript and passing that as data to your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these comments said,the name you pass is not correct.But if you do not want to change the name of the inputs,you could use FormData and append the input data with specify name like below:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var formdata = new FormData();
         $('#QuestionsForm').find(".group:checked").each(function () {
             formdata.append("group", $(this).val());
         });
         $('#QuestionsForm').find(".trueFalse:checked").each(function () {
             formdata.append("trueFalse", $(this).val());
         });
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#QuestionsForm').attr('action'),
            method: "Post",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status === 'success') {
                alert("succeed");
            }
            else if (res.status === 'faild') {
                alert("faild");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Model:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public List<string> group { get; set; }
    public List<string> trueFalse { get; set; }
    public string Descriptive { get; set; }
    public List<ChoiceQuestionSelection> choiceQuestionSelection { get; set; }
    public List<TrueFalseQuestions> trueFalseQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Question>

@{

    var i = 0;
    var trueFalse = 0;
    var QuestionCount = 0;
}
<form id="QuestionsForm" asp-action="SubmitAnswers" asp-controller="Home" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-
      method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="well well-lg">
                <h4>@item.QuestionTitle</h4>
                <p>
                    @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                    {
                        @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
                        {
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" data-choice="@i" name="group@(i)" class="group"
                                       value="@choice.Choice">@choice.Choice
                                </label>
                            }
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    @if (item.trueFalseQuestions.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                    {
                        <!--truefalse-->

                        @foreach (var question in item.trueFalseQuestions)
                        {
                            var convertToString = Convert.ToString(question.IsTrue);
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)"
                                       name="trueFalse@(trueFalse)" class="trueFalse" value="صحیح">صحیح
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" data-selection="@(trueFalse)"
                                       name="trueFalse@(trueFalse)" class="trueFalse" value="غلط">غلط
                            </label>

                        }
                        trueFalse++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" name="QId" value="@item.QuestionId" />
                        <textarea class="descriptive" name="Descriptive" id="descriptive"
                                  placeholder="..."></textarea>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        QuestionCount++;
    }
    <input type="button" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="save">
</form>
```

Result:

[image]